# Heterogeneous Lists, Virtual Functions, and Member Data

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, heterogeneous

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to assign values to member data when calling a virtual function through a heterogeneous list.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class A
{
 protected:
 virtual void func1();

 private:
 A * list;
}

class B: public A
{
 protected:
 void func1();

 private:
 int i1, i2;
}
```

Within main():

```
list = new A[10];

list[0] = new B;

list[0]->Func1();
```

Declaration of Func1():

```
void B::Func1()
{
 int a, b;

 cin >> a >> b;

 list[0]->i1 = a;
 list[0]->i2 = b;

 // or can I just do this:
 // i1 = a;
 // i2 = b;
}
```

I'm looking for the appropriate way to access member data of a derived class within a function of the derived class if calling via a pointer of the parent class from main.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The way you have commented out is the correct way.

Comment: Thanks!  I was worried that calling through an A pointer type would make assigning the data members directly not work.  But that clears it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While executing a `virtual` function you now that the type of the object is the type of class the function is defined in or a class derived thereof. That is, in your `B::func1()` function you know `this` points to a `B` object. The object may be of a type derived from`B` but you still have everything present in `B`.

On the other hand, you *don't* know statically that `list[0]` points to `B` object. The code you have uncommented in your code does not work. The commented code looks OK

Comment: I see.  So the compiler doesn't know syntactically which object a pointer to the base class that has an object attached to it dynamically is pointing to until runtime?  So I can't access member data of a non-base class through the arrow operator attached to a base class pointer?